# Firebase cloud functions node 8 - "Error: Can't find env config" when deploying remotely

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing my firebase cloud functions in typescript with node 8. In order to access the firebase storage bucket from cloud functions, I initialise my CFs in `index.ts` in the following way to enable switching between prod and dev firebase projects:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
import * as geofunctions from 'geofirestore'

if(!process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG){
    throw Error("Can't find env config")
}

const adminConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG)
const projectId = adminConfig.projectId

const certPath = projectId + '.json'
const bucketUrl = projectId + '.appspot.com'

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(certPath),
    storageBucket: bucketUrl
});
```

This is in accordance with:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start

This works fine when running locally e.g.: `firebase -P dev serve`

However, when I deploy remotely using `firebase deploy -P dev --only functions`, it fails for all functions with the following error:

```
⚠  functions[<<MY FUNCTION NAME>>(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file lib/index.js can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Can't find env config
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/lib/index.js:7:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at getUserFunction (/worker/worker.js:439:24)
    at loadUserCode (/worker/worker.js:495:18)
```

The key line is: `Error: Can't find env config`

When I remove `process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG` and hardcode the auth details, it works fine remotely.

As a work-around, I'm using `process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT` to get my projectId - which does work for remote deployment.

I'm using the latest firebase dependencies - see my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.2.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^7.3.2",
    ...
},
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6",
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.3"
    ...
  },
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?